# C++ runtime member function access by string name

Tags: c++, function-pointers

I have two classes:

```
class MyClassInfo {
public:
  void AddMethod(std::string name, void* pointer); // I don't know what signature should be
}
class MyClass
{
public: 
  void SetField1(int f1);
  int GetFileld1();
private:
  int field1;
};
```

I need to be able to access the methods of `MyClass` by name (string) during runtime. I don't want to use any libraries (except boost) and/or compiler functionality (such as rtti) to do that.

I don't know which signature I should use in `AddMethod` method, because I don't know how to transmit the function pointer to the function. This function must be a universal function which allows to add any method. Maybe you know a better variant how to do that without `MyClassInfo`. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: "I don't want to use any libraries (except boost) and/or compiler functionality (such as rtti) to do that" - Sorry, do you mean you *don't* want to use RTTI?

Comment: `I don't want to use any libraries (except boost) and/or compiler functionality (such as rtti) to do that.` Why not? Why not go just one step further and add a requirement not to use the C++ language that ISO ratified for you.

Comment: It could add additional overhead. If you think, it won't, add your advice, plz.

Comment: Overhead ? What kind of overhead are you concerned about ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is not possible in directly C++. You will have to look at alternatives like creating a map of names to member function pointers. But even that would require consistent method signatures.

Something like

```
std::map<std::string, int (MyClass::*)(void*))
```

for instance. Your `AddMethod` signature would then look like this

```
void AddMethod(std::string name, int (MyClass::* pointer)(void*));
```

and you would call it like this

```
info.AddMethod("someMethod", &MyClass::someMethod);
```

Comment: I know that C++ does not have such runtime info. And yes, I need to create something like map.

Comment: But it won't be universal because you are writing the return type in the method signature.

Comment: @user14416 Yes this is true. I'm not sure how much better you can do in C++. Maybe you should be using a different language?

Comment: There's not much use to access functions with different signatures (return types or parameters) by string - you wouldn't be able to call them.

Answer (score 0):

If all functions you want to pass through `AddMethod` have the same signature (possibly after binding some of the arguments), you can use this signature:

```
void AddMethod(std::string name, boost::function<int ()> func);
```

and use like this:

```
info.AddMethod("GetFileId1", std::bind1st(std::mem_fun(&MyClass::GetFileId1), &MyClassInstance);
```

If the functions have different signatures, you could store them using `boost::function_base`:

```
void AddMethod(std::string name, boost::function_base func);
```

and you use it like above. The challenge is now to find out exactly what type is stored in the `boost::function` object so you can use it.

Comment: With C++11 lambdas, the variable binding is much simpler.

Comment: @Sebgastian: That is right, and so is using `boost::bind`. I just gave an example using binding.