# C++ method resolution by name

Tags: c++, templates, reflection, template-meta-programming, higher-order-functions

I am wondering if there is a way in C++ to write a function that will resolve object methods based on the method name alone (specific examples below). Run time or compile time resolution (such as templates) would both be acceptable. I have read a little bit about template metaprogramming, but I was hoping I might get some info as to whether that is even the appropriate direction for my problem before delving to deep into that.

Essentially, I am trying to write a function that will call non-static methods of a passed in object, such as this psuedocode:

```
exampleFunction(Object myObject, ObjectMethod myObjectMethod) {
    // do some stuff here

    myObject.myObjectMethod(arguments);

    // do some more stuff here
}
```

In this case, I cannot hard-code a method into `exampleFunction` and simply have every object that I call it with have that method name. I must have the flexibility to call `exampleFunction` with a variety of methods, and have each of those methods properly resolve. Further, I must be able to resolve *methods*, and those methods must be *non-static*. In my case, I must be able to modify internal, private object members on the method call. Without going into the details, these constraints are an artifact of the system I am working on that I cannot change.

As I previously stated, both compile time and run time solutions are acceptable. So something like this with templates would work perfectly well in my case as well:

```
template <ObjectMethodName methodName>
exampleFunction(Object myObject) {
    // do some stuff here

    myObject.methodName(arguments);

    // do some more stuff here
}
```

Any thoughts on whether this is possible, as well as information on possible implementation would be appreciated.

Comment: Related, if not a dupe: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13273906/c-runtime-member-function-access-by-string-name

Comment: We're not talking non-static members of the same class, are we?   It's several different classes, possibly unrelated?

Comment: Use a `std::map<string, function-pointer>` or a table of `<function-name, function-pointer`.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Related, but not dupe. That's run time specific. A solution in my case would either be run time or compile time. In either case, thanks for the link, I'll take a look.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews Will a function-pointer like that work in the case of a non-static method? Excuse my ignorance if there is essentially no difference between a function and method pointer in this case, I generally work with interpreted languages so I don't have a really strong grasp of how everything works under the hood.

Comment: Depends on how you declare or define the structures.  If you want to use member functions, then use pointers to member functions.  For static and free-standing functions, use the pointer to free-standing function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make `exampleFunction` a **function template** that has the first parameter of type of the object, the second parameter can be a reference to a pointer to a member function and the third parameter is a function parameter pack that denotes the arguments to be passed when calling the member function.

```
#include <iostream>

class Actions {
  public:
    Actions(){}
    void doSmthg(){
        std::cout<<"do something called"<<std::endl;
    }
    void multipleArgs(int, int)
    {
        std::cout<<"multiple int args called"<<std::endl;
    }
};
class Entity
{
    public:
    void func(double)
    {
        std::cout<<"func called"<<std::endl;
    }
};
template<typename T, typename Callable, typename... Args>
void exampleFunction(T obj, const Callable& callable, const Args&... args){
    std::cout<<"exampleFunction called"<<std::endl;
    //call the function on the passed object
    (obj.*callable)(args...);
}


int main()
{
    Actions action;
    
    exampleFunction(action, &Actions::doSmthg); //calls doSmthg member function with 0 arguments 
    exampleFunction(action, &Actions::multipleArgs, 5,7);//calls multipleArgs member function with 2 int arguments
    
    Entity e;
    exampleFunction(e, &Entity::func,4.4); //calls func member function 
}
```

[Demo](https://onlinegdb.com/jmeKu4qhZ)

The output of the above program is:

```
exampleFunction called
do something called
exampleFunction called
multiple int args called
exampleFunction called
func called
```

Comment: Wait, sorry, but I was playing around with this and I'm not sure it works. Will this allow me to change internal components of the object? I gave action an int variable and had doSmthg increment that int, however the change wasn't persistent after the method was called. I'm not really too familiar with pointers to methods, is this unavoidable in this solution?

Comment: @ad010203 you just need to take a reference to action then, instead of a copy

Comment: @ad010203 Pass the object by reference if you want the change to be reflected in the original object. See [live increment demo](https://onlinegdb.com/L9CI3Kffv). In the linked demo above, i have added a comment highlighting where the reference should be added.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible to pass a pointer-to-member-function as a template parameter.

Here is one example approach.

```
#include <iostream>

struct Foo {
    void print() {
        std::cout << "Foo\n";
    }

    void printVal(int val) {
        std::cout << "val = " << val << "\n";
    }
};

template <auto F, typename T, typename... Args>
void exampleFunc(T& obj, Args&&... args) {
    (obj.*F)(args...);
}

int main()
{
    Foo foo;
    exampleFunc<&Foo::print>(foo);
    exampleFunc<&Foo::printVal>(foo, 5);
}
```

Using `auto` template parameters requires c++17.

Comment: This was my first thought, but unfortunately, I don't think it will fulfill OP's requirements.